# How do I disable resize lag when using vw units and a transition duration?

Tags: css

See below: (You'll need to go into fullscreen mode for it to work, I think)

```css
p {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  font-size: 3vw;
}
```

```html
<p>Rescale the window with control+scroll</p>
```

Comment: @AleshaOleg I would not be opposed to it.

Comment: I'm don't sure, but I think you can use [this](https://github.com/tombigel/detect-zoom) to detect zoom level of browser and than change your font-size when user zoom in/out page